# Не работает код с фрагментом

Tags: android, android-fragment, kotlin, fragment-transaction

Добрый день! Помогите разобраться, почему фрагмент не работает. 
Код MainActivity:

```
class MainActivityNew: AppCompatActivity() {

lateinit var mFragmentTransaction: FragmentTransaction

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_new)

    mFragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    var stor = StorageNew()
    mFragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, stor).commit()
}
```

Код activtiy_main_new:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.lev.homechek.view.MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    app:title="@string/nav_news"
    app:titleTextColor="@color/white"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:popupTheme="@style/android:Theme.Holo.Light"
    android:theme="@style/MainMenu"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Код StorageNew:

```
 class StorageNew: Fragment() {

fun newInstance(): Fragment {
    return StorageNew()
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {

    var view = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_storage_new, container)

    return view
}
```

}

Код fragment_storage_new:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout
  android:orientation="vertical"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:hint="Search"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/choose"
    android:entries="@array/producer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Log:

```
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

И никаких ссылок на код в моих классах

Comment: это kotlin?) попробуйте вместо `mFragmentTransaction.add` - `mFragmentTransaction.replace`. Навскидку пока так :)

Comment: Попробуйте добавить тут (`var view = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_storage_new, container)`) ещё аргумент -  `var view = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_storage_new, container, false)`

Comment: В место fragmentManager, используйте supportFragmentManager, а так же убедитесь, что ваш фрагмент из пакета android.support.v4.app